# Multi valued column in SQL

Tags: sql, database, ddl

I created a table for Boat that contains the following columns: `BName, Type, Price, OName`.

However, the `Type` column should be one of the following: Sailboat, Houseboat, or Deckboat.

How can I reflect this on the create table statement. I've searched about it and I came up with this statement which I'm not sure if it's right or not:

```
CREATE TABLE Boat
(
    BName varchar(255),
    BType int,
    Price double,
    OName varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (BName),
    FOREIGN KEY (BType) REFERENCES BoType(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE BoType
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Type varchar(255)
)
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Looks pretty good. If some of your data can be considered as separate entity (in your case boat type) then it's a common way to store it in separate table and build foreign key to ensure consistency.

Comment: The only thing I would change is change the `int` type of your PK on `BoType` to `tinyint` and the same for `BType` on `Boat`. This will save 3 bytes per row. FoggyDay's answer works also, but if you start having more boat types it will get cumbersum

Comment: Tinyint isn't an ANSI/ISO SQL datatype. Stick with integer. Also add unique constraints, for example for boattype. Perhaps NOT NULL is a good idea for some of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

That's the best way to do it just make sure that you populate the `BoType` table with the desired reference values (i.e. Sailboat, Houseboat, Deckboat). Because if you use constraint then you have the user of the database who have no knowledge in SQL or have no access rights in your DB, at your mercy or they become too dependent on you. However, if you set it as a separate table then the user of your system/database even without knowledge about SQL could add or change values via your `front-end` program (e.g. `ASP`, `PHP`). In other words you design is more flexible and scalable not to mention less maintenance in your part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

`mycol VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (mycol IN('moe', 'curley', 'larry'))`

Here are more details on MSSQL "Check Constraints":

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: What if OP someday will want to extend types? In your case it will be nessesary to alter column, but in OP's proposed case it will be enough just to add one more record to `BoType` table (this can be done even by end-user via some UI, but your proposition require database administration).